# Why are null values in your tables a bad thing to have?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm reading a post about single table inheritance and polymorphism in Rails and I came across this sentence:

> STI isn’t always the best design choice for your schema. If
>   sub-classes that you intend to use for STI have many different data
>   fields, then including them all in the same table would result in a
>   lot of null values and make it difficult to scale over time. In this
>   case, you may end up with so much code in your model sub-classes that
>   the shared functionality between sub-classes is minimal and warrants
>   separate tables.

Why is having null values in your table cells a bad thing? Does it take up memory? Does it slow down queries? What makes it bad?

Comment: Potentially because `null`s aren't "real values". Sure, they can indicate a failure or an absence of a value, but they can't actually be used. That means any time you need to read in a value that may be null, you need to do checks before it's used, else you end up with "null contamination" which leads to NPEs in potentially confusing places.

Comment: Got an example? I can give you credit for a more fleshed out answer.

Comment: I don't really have an example directly related to the domain of your question, which is why I made this a comment. It was just a stab. I have no idea if it's what the author of the post intended.

Answer (score 3):

That comment could be worded a little better. There is nothing wrong with NULL values specifically.  Imagine you have a `Transportation` model that you STI. `Car` inherits. `Bike` inherits. Your model has `num_wheels` attributes. And in general life is good.  Then you add `Boat`, which is fine, but will never use `num_wheels`, but you don't mind. Then you add `SailBoat` which needs `num_masts` and now you're a little concerned because that field will never be used by `Car` or `Bike` or `Boat`, but you keep going. And say you have 10 million rows in your database.

Then you add `Airplane` which needs a `wingspan` field. Stored as an Integer. Now you have 10 million rows of data with a never-to-be-used `wingspan` Integer field. Worse if you add another 5 million airplanes, they all have never-to-be-used `num_masts` fields.

At some point that is going to take up a fair amount of disk space and make your life miserable.  I think that is what they mean by not always being the best choice.

Comment: So it does take disk space?

Comment: Yes. Some fields more than others.